# Illustrator • Permanent Shear Rectangles

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is a self-answered question.

This has been asked before, but I did not see a solution in the forum.
I did find the answer myself (at least for my case) and I wanted to share it with you guys, as it was the reason that brought me here in the first place.

For the record, the original question I saw is posted with the following name: "Illustrator - my rectangles are all sheared skewed?"

I could not add a comment on that question, so I decided to do this to help others with the same problem.

Final detail: Original answer was deleted, as it was created in the Q&A format.

With that out of the way, here is what I found that worked for me...

[image]

Comment: Please post the question as it's own entity, then click on the **Answer Your Question** button on the bottom and add the answer as an answer.

Comment: If it's an existing question why don't you answer it there instead of creating a duplicate??

Comment: Evening.
I could not reply on that because it was removed due to low attraction, and I did not have enough rank to be able to do so.

Comment: I will do that, answer my question. Thanks for the tip. I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a sheared box/rectangle everytime you use the "Rectangle Tool" you may notice a weird active cursor.

[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRqFJ.png)

First, check the icon in the top-left hand corner of your program, in the arboard.

[image]

To resolve this, you will need to select your "Perspective Grid Tool" (Shift+P) first, and then interact with the icon in the top left corner. It will have a little x. Click on it and that was it.

[image]

Fixed.